# Downloading an HLS stream: ONLY in sync when downloading with ffmpeg. Possible explanations?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, audio, sync, hls

I'm trying to download a livestream that is just a plain hls with no encryption. I usually use streamlink, but this site I'm trying to use recently doesn't output a correct video/audio synced output when downloaded with streamlink/yt-dlp/nm3u8dl etc.

The only option that produces the correct output with the audio and video in sync is ffmpeg, but ffmpeg is very user-unfriendly and lacks functionality related to retries when connection is lost, and etc.

This is super weird cuz when I play the hls stream using VLC or any other livestream supported players, they are on sync. But what I do noticed is that when I play them on a player, the audio is mute for a second or two and then plays the audio correctly.

Can anyone possibly explain the cause of this situation and probably a fix? I would love to use streamlink instead of ffmpeg.